# Проблема парсинга при чтения с файла txt

Tags: java, строки, парсер

Записал сущность Hotel в файл, потом с файла хочу достать данные чтобы написать дополнительную логику.  При работе метода **public Hotel parseToRead(String line)**, в классе **DAO Hotel**.  *String id* не парситься в *long id*
Подскажите пожалуйста в чем ошибка и как это исправить?

**Сущность**

```
Hotel hotel1 = new Hotel(1L, "Ajax", "Holland", "Amsterdam", "Amsterdamskaja");
```

**Класс записи и чтения**

```
public abstract class MainDAO<T> {
private String pathToDB;

public String getPathToDB() {
    return pathToDB;
}

public static void writeToFile(String pathToFile, String dataFile) throws Exception {
    Validation.validate(pathToFile);
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(pathToFile, true))) {
        try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(pathToFile))) {
            if (br.readLine() != null) {
                bw.append("\n");
            }
            bw.append(dataFile);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IOException("File" + pathToFile + " cannot be edited.");
    }
}

public T addObject(T object) throws Exception {
    writeToFile(getPathToDB(), object.toString());
    return object;
}

//public abstract String parsToWrite(T t);
public abstract T parseToRead(String line) throws Exception;

public List<T> readToFile() throws Exception {
    List<T> objectsList = new ArrayList<>();
    String line;
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(getPathToDB()))) {
        line = br.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            objectsList.add(parseToRead(line));
            line = br.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new Exception("File " + getPathToDB() + " cannot be read.");
    }
    return objectsList;
}
```

}

**DAO class Hotel**

```
public class HotelDAO extends MainDAO<Hotel> implements HotelInterface {
Path path = new Path();

@Override
public String getPathToDB() {
    return path.hotelDB;
}

@Override
public Hotel addHotel(Hotel hotel) throws Exception {
    Random random = new Random();
    hotel.setId(random.nextInt());
    if (hotel.getId() < 0) {
        hotel.setId(-1 * hotel.getId());
    }
    return super.addObject(hotel);
}

@Override
public Hotel parseToRead(String line) throws Exception {
    String[] arr = line.split(",");
    return new Hotel(Long.parseLong(arr[0]), arr[1], arr[2], arr[3], arr[4]);
}

@Override
public List<Hotel> getHotels() throws Exception {
    return super.readToFile();
}
```

}

**Запись  данных в txt файле**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Ошибка**
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь распарсить строку `Hotel{id=...`.
Вам необходимо переопределить метод toString() в вашем классе, чтобы он записывал так:

```
1,"Ajax","Holland","Amsterdam","Amsterdamskaja"
```

Например) формат csv, чтоли. Либо возпользуйтесь какой-нибудь библиотекой, которая записывает в json, либо стандартный Serializable

Comment: В классе сущности, переопределил метод toString. То есть добавил только чтобы стринг брал id. А можете обьяснить почему именно так работает? 
 `@Override
    public String toString() {
        return getId() + "," +
                name + "," +
                country + "," +
                city + "," +
                street;
    }`